# Is there potential security vulnerabilities with connection.js or any reason why should we rewrite existing pages without using this lib?

Tags: visualforce, ajax-toolkit, sforce.connection

I work on one of the projects with assessment activities and there are a bunch of Visualforce pages that use the [Connections.js library from the AJAX toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_connecting.htm).

As for me, security is the number one priority of a solution. I am wondering is there any reason I would recommend to start rewriting those pages without connection.js dependency? Are there any potential issues with connection.js today or in the future you know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AJAX Toolkit uses the Salesforce APIs, which are governed by the user's Profile and Permission Set permissions. If you're concerned about this script, you should also be concerned that simply having the "Api Enabled" permission would allow them to use a smorgasbord of other tools with just as much functionality, from browser extensions to apps they could install on their computer, or even scripts they could write themselves in the browser's Developer Console.

It is no more of a security risk than any other tool, so there's no compelling reason to not use it unless you also plan on turning off the "Api Enabled" permission, in which case, you'd have to rewrite your pages because they would no longer work as intended. As long as your user profiles are properly configured, there is no inherent security risk related to this script as compared to any other.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox for the detailed answer.